# Running 2.0 applications in .net 4.0 app pool

Tags: asp.net, backwards-compatibility

I recently migrated our webservice and asp applications built with target framework 2.0 to a new server. The application was setup in 4.0 app pool. The application and the service are running fine most of the time. Except some times the worker processes of my webservice piles up and stops responding to the clients. The admin is complaining the setup was not right and wants to set this up in 2.0 app pool. I believe 4.0 should be backward compatible and this change will not yield any result. Any inputs?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic].  Try re-tagging as [tag:asp.net].

Comment: Without any information it's impossible to answer. What does "most of the time" mean? There *are* incompatibilities, they *are* documented, but that would lead to exceptions, not a server meltdown. Are there any exceptions, do you log what is going on, did you check the requests that are stuck in IIS? Have you tried stress testing the application? Meltdowns occurs due to coding errors like unintended recursion, ignoring exceptions retrying indiscriminately, concurrency errors, etc